# SQL Select * and cast one of those variables

Tags: sql, teradata

I am working in TeraData and I want to select **all** the columns in a table **except I need to cast one of them**.  Is there an easy way to do this **without writing all of the column names out every time**?

This describes what I want to do:

```
SELECT top 500 *,
       cast( cast(var AS format 'Z(I)' ) AS varchar(18) ) as casted_var
FROM db.tbl
```

Comment: Nope, not unless you want to use `dynamic sql` . . .

Comment: Using * is bad practice anyway. You should write them out every time.

Comment: Can you use a view ?  (I'm an Oracle guy, so not sure about teradata .. but a view might help a bit with that.)

Comment: Writing them out every time is not an option.  Selecting hundreds of variables from these tables.

Comment: And I could use a view if that helps?

Comment: If you alias your table, you can do it: `select top 500 t1.*, cast(..) as <some clever alias> from db.tbl t1`.  However as others have said, it's better to write out the select list.

Comment: I think that is the answer I am looking for @Andrew.  I can choose that as the answer if you write it as one.  The purpose of this query is to see what is inside of the table so I wouldn't know the column names before running the query and there are hundreds of columns so writing them out is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you alias your table, you can do it:

```
select top 500 t1.*, 
cast(..) as <some clever alias> 
from db.tbl t1.
```

However as others have said, it's better to write out the select list.1